# Getting a list of points on a path

Tags: snap.svg

How could I  *access and enumerate* through control points and their coordinates in **svg/snapsvg** path?

Something like:

```
 var myPath = s.path("M 18,0 4.5,9 13.5,9 9,18 0,36 18,36 36,0 z");

 myPath.attr("d").forEach(function(point)
 {
 console.log("x:"+point.x," y:"+point.y)
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the segments of the path (the positions/coordinates you entered when creating the path) as such:

```
var numberOfItems = myPath.node.pathSegList.numberOfItems; // handy for loops
var firstCoordinate = myPath.node.pathSegList.getItem(0);
console.log firstCoordinate.x;
console.log firstCoordinate.y;
```

Comment: `pathSegList` is now deprecated and removed. Was it cross-browser or chrome-only to begin with?